# Avoid repetitvely downloading packages when upgrading several environments?

Tags: anaconda

I have several different environments in anaconda. When I try to upgrade all those environments via `conda update --all` after use "source .../activate [env ]" it downloadeds all packages for each environment separately.

However, most packages are exactly the same... is there any way I can avoid downloading the same packages for each environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When updating or installing a package with conda it will check if that exact package already exists in the ~/anaconda/pkgs directory. If the exact package is present conda will link this package rather than downloading it again. You should see the list of packages being downloaded in the output:

```
The following packages will be downloaded:

package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
```

and what is being installed to the environment:

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:
```

Packages listed under the "UPDATED" section  and not under the "downloaded" section are being linked from the ~/anaconda/pkgs/ directory.